# Scraping Html with Attributes

Tags: java, android, html, web-scraping, jsoup

```
<tr valign="middle" align="center"> 
<td><b>someNumbers</b></td>
<td width="22" height="22" background="..." class="SomeIntrestingClass">xxxxx</td>
<td width="22" height="22" background="..." class="SomeIntrestingClass">xgdsx</td> 
<td width="22" height="22" background="..." class="SomeIntrestingClass">xyzzx</td>
<td width="22">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Im making an application that needs data from website. I need to extract the values in 'someNumbers' and the values in the td ex:'xyzzx'...

The problem I am having is 'someNumbers doesn't have a class so I tried to use 
`doc.getElementsByAttributeValue(key, value)`
 but the attribute there are the same in other parts of the document. How can I extract these values using JSoup or any other bright ideas? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you select all the `td` and get only the text content?

Comment: I can just select the td tag. But that will result 1k results and I'm just using 30% of that which 'someNumbers' will be very hard to distinguish. But ill try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Document.select(...);`  What this method does, we are able to use 'css selectors' like `td.class` or `tr td #id` and just use them as if they were css selectors in this [article](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) in Jsoup.

Answer (score -1):

`<td[^<]+?>*</[^<]+?>` use this as the regular expression and store it all in an array

then remove each one by removing `<td[^<]+?>` and then this `</[^<]+?>`.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)